# custom navigation bar with image and two titles in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, large-title, preferslargetitles

I am trying to achieve the following navigation bar with two titles and an image:

Large title variant:

[image: large]

Small title variant:

[image: small]

I tried subclassing `UINavigationBar` and adding subviews to it, but they did not render at all.
I tried setting a `titleView` in storyboard, however it seemed like the titleView is constrained in its height.

What is the proper way to achieve this custom navigation bar?

I also tried this (and setting the viewController in Storyboard to that class):

```
class NavViewController: UINavigationController {

    var titleView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView?.backgroundColor = .gray
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 300)
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleView
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: have you tried larageNavigationBar property, will give feature for make navigation bar in both sizes as large and small? 
Also instead of adding it on titleView add it on navigationbar because titleView have fixed size which is not changes as per content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `ViewController`in `viewDidLoad`, add `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)`. (no need for subclassing)
There is even support for AutoLayout inside UINavigationbar, which is great for animation.

Answer (score 0):

Design your custom view seprately in a xib file, then set that xib as the titleview for your navigationbar

```
self.navBar.topItem?.titleView = logoImage
```

Do this for large title, for the smaller one only populate an image in the titleView.

Comment: I tried that using a simple UIView() with a background color. In the NavigationController class, I set the frame of that view and set that as the titleView, but nothing will be rendered. I update the question, so that you can better see, that I did.